# Client Server Communication : Windows Services / Networking / Windows 7 / Wireshark

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, client-server, wireshark, tcp

Dear all we have designed a windows service (installed in server), in .Net and C#,  a multithreaded program that listens to clients, assigns a dedicated thread to each client, streams client data and store it in the Server. This Service runs perfectly for months but after windows update (windows 7)  there is a connection failure in random time.  We don’t see any error either in server or in client. The Service event log is also normal, "waiting to listen for a client".

We used Wireshark to trace the TCP/IP packets and found that TCP/IP packets enter the server port (60000) but the service doesn't receive any packet. This proves that our LAN network is working normally.

But after a restart the Service runs perfectly.

If anyone can throw some light on this that would be helpful. ( I have tried to keep the text as simple as possible, feel free to ask for more details).